# Alignmento Facebook and Twitter buttons Joomla

Tags: facebook, twitter, joomla

I would like to know how can I align the Facebook and twitter buttons, that I've put in my website top bar. I want one in front of the other and not one below. I used module extensions for both of them from Joomla extension directory. Please take a look at .

Comment: The website is gybr . com . br

Answer (score 0):

Add to the CSS (in your templates custom css file if possible as that should stop anything being overwritten):

```
.udtwitterfollow, .VombieLikeButton { float:left; padding: 0 2px; }
```

The `float:left` is all you need to keep then in-line - but the padding just adds a small amount of separation between them.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great man! Worked like a charm! Just one more thing, how do I align it to the right just before the search box?? And one other strange thing is on Chrome the search box's button is aligned ok beside the box, but with IE the button appears under the box, how do I fix this??

Comment: I got the float right to align the buttons. I just can't figure out the search box button in Internet Explorer. The CSS file looks like this:

Comment: #zt-top{ height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color:#37383B;}
#zt-top1 { float: left;}
#zt-top2 { float: right; margin:0;}
#zt-top3 { float: right;  }
#zt-top3 form{ margin:0; }
.box-search{ height: 28px; border:1px solid #454649; border-right: 0; background:#2a2b2f; margin:0 ; float:left;}
.box-search .inputbox {  border: 0; color: #dfdfdf; margin: 0; padding: 4px 10px; width: 119px; background:0; }

Comment: .box-search .button {  background: #26282c url('../images/bkg-search.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; border: 0; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; font-size: 105%; font-weight: bold; height: 28px; line-height: 28px; padding: 0 15px; }
.box-search .button  span{ display: none;}